# Can we say, "can have to" like in,"You can have to buy me a new phone if you drop it"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-choice

As far as I know, we can say "might have to" or "may have to", but I think I am not used to "can have to." Can we say, "can have to" like in this sentence I thought of: "You can have to buy me a new phone if you drop it." I know we can say, "You may/might have to buy me a new phone if you drop it (my phone)", but how about the phrase "can have to"? Is it generally ever usable?

Answer (score 2):

No, we don't say "can have to."

Generally the options are:

> You may/might have to do x. (possibility)
>
> You could have to do x. (possibility)
>
> You **will** have to do x. (certainty)

Comment: Also possible is "You have to buy me a new phone if you drop it." This is also expressing certainty.

Comment: You could also say "You can buy me a new phone if you break it." (without the "have to"). Although "can" seems to express possibility, in that use it has an air of threat.

Comment: Thank you. How about "You can need to"? Is it used? It sounds like it might be wrong as well to me.

Comment: "You could have to" also sounds wrong to me unless it is used in indirect speech.